# Values not getting stored in array

Tags: jsp

hie, 
i am trying to insert values into an array by getting each value from previous page (dynamic).  The problem is that these values are not getting stored in the array. Null values are being shown.The code is as follows.

```
String ins[][] = new String[numb][2];

for(int i=0;i<numb;i++)
{
String frwd = "frwd"+String.valueOf(i);
String posn = "posn"+String.valueOf(i);

ins[i][0] = request.getParameter("frwd");
ins[i][1] = request.getParameter("posn");
 }
```

numb being the number or rows in the previous page and [2] represents the number of dynamic columns .. Please guide me ..

Comment: Please, clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes in your request.getParameter calls:

```
ins[i][0] = request.getParameter(frwd);
ins[i][1] = request.getParameter(posn);
```